# Gradient of $\operatorname{tr} \left( \left( C C^{T} \right)^{-1} \right)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

What is the following gradient?

$$\nabla_C \operatorname{tr} \left( \left( C C^{T} \right)^{-1} \right)$$

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Which definition of derivative with respect to a matrix are you using?

Comment: i use ${\partial(tr(C*C^{T})^{-1})}/{\partial C}$

Comment: right but C is a matrix, not a scalar, so that's why I'm confused

Comment: it's true, it can be calculated like https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf   pg:12 but i couldnt

Comment: I think @William might be confused because there are different conventions on matrix derivatives. You want to be consistent with the Matrix cookbook.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you are right @Memming. I tried to find this solution for machine learning problem. So, i generally use cookbook, and i dont know different conventions on matrix derivative.

Comment: Oh haha thanks yeah I did not know these conventions. @ncalik Where did you find this problem? I did not know matrix derivatives had applications in machine learning

Comment: i have an optimization problem. this term is its penalty term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, define the variable
$$\eqalign{
  X &= CC^T \cr
 dX &= dC\,C^T + C\,dC^T \cr\cr
}$$
Write the function in terms of $X$ and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
  f &= {\rm tr}(X^{-1}) \cr
 df &= -X^{-2T}:dX \cr
    &= -X^{-2T}:(dC\,C^T + C\,dC^T) \cr
    &= -(X^{-2T}C:dC + C^TX^{-2T}:dC^T) \cr
    &= -(X^{-2T}C + X^{-2}C):dC \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius Inner Product.

Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial C}:dC\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial C} &= -(X^{-2T} + X^{-2})\,C \cr
}$$

Comment: thanks @Iynn, its a pretty solution.

Comment: @ lynn  . $X^T=X$;

Comment: @loupblanc  Thanks, that simplifies the solution a bit,